# Jenkins Slave on Windows

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a new requirement to configure a Windows 10 VM as Jenkins Slave and run certain python scripts.
I am currently using multi-branch pipeline and use Jenkins file to define different stages.

**Issue :** Jenkins is not able to recognize where python is :
F:\Jenkins\workspace\test>python --version
Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640

Python works from the command line but not from Jenkins..
F:\Jenkins\workspace\test>python --version
Python 3.8.5

I tried defining PYTHONPATH variable in the manage node section of Jenkins ( Under the windows configuration ), but it is still not able to recognize it.

any suggestions ??

```
jenkinsfile : 
 stage('Lint') {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat '''
                      python --version
                      // C:\Python\python.exe --version  
                      // Tried to run the executable but no luck 
                      '''
                }
```

Comment: Does the Jenkins user has executable permission for Python. Please check the permissions once.

Answer (score 1):

Since on windows after the installation of something (ex.: java) requires the restart of the command line to call it successfully, my bet would be on **restarting Jenkins**.